# allign css triangle for active links

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to create a triangle for the hover over links , but my triangle is always showing at one corner not below the links.Could anyone tell me where is the exact problem?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKnyQ/)

```
 #navcontainer a:hover::after {
            background: white;
            border: solid black;
            border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
            bottom: -5px;
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            height: 10px;
            left: 32px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            z-index: 99;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is apply the hover effect to the LI instead of the A.

```
#navcontainer li:hover::after {
```

instead of

```
#navcontainer a:hover::after {
```

You also need to change the display type of the LI to inline-block and give it a height (minus the padding top from the UL) and finally a position relative to contain the arrow.

```
    #navcontainer ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        height:35px;
        position:relative;
    }
```

Now for the hover. We know it's 10px wide so to position it centrally we do a calculation, 50% of the width - 5px (half of the width of the arrow);

```
    #navcontainer li:hover::after {
        background: white;
        border: solid black;
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
        bottom: -5px;
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        height: 10px;
        left: calc(50% - 5px);
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
        z-index: 99;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
```

The arrow should now be correctly positioned.

Comment: hi, the above code is not working properly in IE(11).Any idea?

Comment: For the transform and transform-origin styles you will need to replace the -webkit- with -ms-. The rest of the CSS is compatible with IE 11 so I assume this could be your problem.

Comment: -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); this piece of code helped me to fix the issue.:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:relative` to `#navcontainer ul li a`

This way, the triangle defined in `:after` is aware of the parent element from which to base its own position.

```
 #navcontainer ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: .2em 1em;
     color: #fff;
     position:relative; /* this is important for correct positioning */
}
```

**[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cKnyQ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```css
#navcontainer a:hover::after {
   /*background: white;*/ /* this was the problem */
   background: blue;      /* now full triangle */
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    left: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```